# To find value of $x$ for which series is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have series as $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n + 1/n}$.

I know tests regarding these questions. BUT HERE MY maindoubt is that given series is alternating, so do i have to see absolute and conditional convergence both here? For absolute convergence i have applied ratio test and got values of $x$, but when iplus end point $x=-1$ i get again a alternating. How do i handle this

Answer (score 1):

You need the alternating series test:
If $\{a_n\}$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence of positive numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^na_n$ converges.

Comment: But first do i haveto check convergence of absolute version

Comment: The series alternates for $x>0$, but it should still (as far as I can see) converge on $(-1,0]$, where all terms have the same sign.

Comment: Yes, check absolute convergence first. If that doesn't work try the alternating series test.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski: Well, if only we knew some complex analysis we could show convergence on $(0,1)$ quickly by the alternating series test, and conclude that the radius of convergence must be $1$, and _therefore_ it converges absolutely when $|x|<1$ ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, that's right, althought I think the OP is asking about convergence at the end points.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski my mainconcern is here that at endpoint -1 , it again becomes a alternating series, its like box in a box .what should i do ?

Comment: Refer to my response to your first comment.

Comment: @godonichia: No, it doesn't alternate at $x=-1$. The sign of $x^n$ still cancels out with $(-1)^n$, so the series is just $\sum_n \frac{-1}{n+1/n}$. By comparison with $\sum_n \frac{-1}{n+1}$ (that is, minus the tail end of the harmonic series), this diverges.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, quite right.